# Framework7 how to route as a sub page

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

I am new with `Framework7` and want to use the single page application template as a subpage and going to load it from another webpage, but while attempting this the main router does not load or maybe I am not doing it correctly?

So the default route is like below.

```
routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    url: "./index.php"
  },
[
```

Now I am attempting to load it like this capturing the id from the external page

```
routes = [
      {
        path: "/:id/",
        url: "./index.php"
      },
    [
```

My external page (not a framework7 page) link is like this.

```
<a href="/product/1/">View Product</a>
```

I also tried this

```
 <a href="http:/localhost/products/product/1/">View Product</a>
```

But I am getting the default page 404 error not the 404 on Framework7 meaning the route is not loading, any suggestion would be great!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried making the route to be :

```
   routes = [
      {
         path: '/product/:id',
         url: 'somepage.html'
      },
     ]
```

the one with a path just `path: /:id` will pass to index an ID and not a product.

I think loading a separate F7 page will do you more good than trying to override the index page

Comment: Yes i have, i ended up converting the main page into a F7 page